# Выполнить действие со столбцами mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой php запрос который копирует данные из таблицы `product_price` в `product`.
Как взять цену `price` из таблицы `product_price` и выполнить с ней просчет по формуле?

```
<?php
$sql2 = "insert into product (price) select price from product_price";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
?>
```

Comment: Пояснение для отвечателей: автору нужен не insert, а update

Comment: @Ипатьев думаю что нужен insert (копирование) а не обновление

Comment: Это не вам, это тем кто будет отвечать.

Comment: @ипатьев может вы поможете?

Comment: очень долго объяснять, поскольку вы не понимаете разницы между  insert и  update и скорее всего не знаете пока про джойны. наберитесь терпения, возможно у кого-то будет больше времени

Comment: @ипатьев а причём тут джойны?

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин это хороший вопрос. Есть такой английский термин, "sanity check", который можно примерно перевести на русский как "защита от дурака". Буквально переводится как проверка осмысленности. Читая вопрос на этом сайте, надо всегда надо проводить такую проверку: "Имеет ли вопрос смысл? Принесет ли кому-либо пользу буквальный ответ на него? В состоянии ли автор сформулировать корректный вопрос? Что нужно сделать, чтобы сделать это за него?" Отвечая себе на эти вопросы, вы увидите, что джойн здесь очевиден

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин не обращайте внимания, это местный сумасшедший.